# AWS service to deal with datas from database

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using Mobile Hub in AWS and I created a NoSQL database (with DynamoDB service) in order to save informations from different users. This works.

Now I would like to compare informations from these different users, in order to make common informations emerge.
I don't know what service could I use. I thought about create an API with CloudLogic or run a Python script on a list from my database.

Have you any idea who permits to do this ?

Comment: tried python boto3?

Comment: yes this suited my needs, thanks